# Difference between Text and ChangeableText

Tags: andengine

What is the difference between Text and ChangeableText in andengine. Since there is no andengine manual i couldnt find the information anywhere

Comment: it's been a while since I used AndEngine - but IIRC, ChangeableText has been deprecated in favor of Text - at least in the GLES2 version of AndEngine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you a referring to the examples there is no difference, both the TextExample and ChangeableTextExample both derive from the Class Text.

All the ChangeableTextExample is showing is how to change the contents contained with your string.